# containers and images gone after docker service stop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker-compose

i had an issue with docker  on my local server, so i restarted it with `sudo service stop docker && sudo service start docker` in order to recreate the docker.sock which was missing and i couldn't use docker commands.

what happened is that all my containers and images and everything i built in docker was gone. The entire /var/lib/docker has 244k worth of size

```
sudo du -h /var/lib/docker/
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/containers
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/metadata/sha256
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/metadata
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content
20K /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/distribution
36K /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2
40K /var/lib/docker/image
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/trust
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/runtimes
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/tmp
36K /var/lib/docker/network/files
40K /var/lib/docker/network
28K /var/lib/docker/volumes
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/swarm
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/plugins/tmp
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/plugins/storage/ingest
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/plugins/storage
16K /var/lib/docker/plugins
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/buildkit/content/ingest
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/buildkit/content
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/buildkit/executor
88K /var/lib/docker/buildkit
244K    /var/lib/docker/
```

running any compose service will start pulling images from the internet instead of local versions even if i installed the updated images less than 3 days ago.

i only have one version of docker

```
$whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/libexec/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
```

I am not sure how this happened, i restarted docker multiple times before and nothing happened. I am running a ubuntu server image and i fear that docker auto-updated and resulted in changing some configuration.
My disk space didn't change though, so i do beleive that a configuration change changed the docker folder i someway, but i don't remember the original configuration of docker i had.

in my containers i had a persisted image with 2y worth of historical data in a mysql db that i need to get back, is there a way to fix this and then i'll deal with the root cause.

docker info :

```
docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.12.2)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.21.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.21
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 78f51771157abb6c9ed224c22013cdf09962315d
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-149-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.228GiB
 Name: <REDACTED>
 ID: G6KW:MUDF:AG7G:XEG6:PGOJ:UIV6:DH2S:7DL3:AJAB:3WSA:I7AP:2GLK
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```